# Coldfusion calling a stored procedure and getting weird error

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have been working on this all day and just cannot figure it out. So I am calling the following from CF:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="SendAlert_follow-up" datasource="#Application.dsn#" debug="yes" returncode="no">            
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" variable="@accountKey" value="11" null="no">    
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" variable="@messageBatchKey" value="D2F91D05-B972-5A1F-98B560558DCFADFB" null="no">    
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" variable="@method" value="t" null="no">    
    <cfprocresult name="theResult">         
</cfstoredproc>
```

And when I run the cfm page, I get this error:

> [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '{'.

I can run it without any problem using the MSSQL Console and it works perfectly.

Here's the beginning of the procedure:

```
USE [db]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SendAlert_follow-up]    Script Date:    11/10/2022 5:59:20 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SendAlert_follow-up]


@accountKey int,    
@messageBatchKey varChar(40), 
@method varChar(255)


AS
```

Has anyone run into this same issue? Thank you very much for any response.

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near '{'.` is interesting. Can you wrap the CF code in a try/catch block? Usually it outputs the bad SQL so you can at least see the full statement that it's trying to execute. Will help us tell where the bracket is coming from.

Comment: I haven't played with ColdFusion since... well, a very long time ago... but have you called many stored procedures with hyphens in their names previously? In T-SQL you'd have to enquote that as `[SendAlert_follow-up]`, but I have no idea what ColdFusion does in this regard.